# Android Studio Gradle not work

Tags: android

When i start a new project in Android studio,it gives an error message like this

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file.

Comment: You should post your app level build.gradle too

Comment: Provided link clearly says `To resolve this issue, simply make sure that you use the same version of each dependency that is common to both your app and its instrumented tests`. So try to user the same version for app and test app. Either `26.1.0` or `27.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem 
in your `build.gradle` change

```
dependencies 

{
...
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
...
}
```

into

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
...
}
```

and

```
andriod{

compileSdkVersion 26 **into compileSdkVersion 27
...**
defaultConfig{
...
targetSdkVersion 26 >> **targetSdkVersion 27**
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer